# Getting a specific (clicked) value from a loop in a Golang template to be used in a Modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, go, templates, range, bootstrap-modal

Here are 2 files that I have created under a directory test. It is a working module running at:

http://localhost:8001/

**test**

```
/main.go
/index.html
```

The requirement is that anytime you click on the vendor code link in the vendacct screen, it should display a modal with the vendor information based on which vend code was clicked. Currently, as it is sat up, it always displays the last vendor value on the modal (as it should because the defined $VC "vend code" in the template is global).

It is a bootstrap modal. I can pass a value to it using the `data-id tag` when the modal is called, but don't know how to retrieve this value in the modal, so, it won't always be the last vend code value. It should be the clicked vend code and then I can use that vend code and pass it to function `"VendorByVendCode()"` and get that specific vendor `$Vend` and use it in the modal.

I have searched and looked at some `javascript` examples, but no luck. If there is a way to retrieve the clicked vend code in the modal, that will be the best option. If not, I can live with a `javascript` solution as well. I am just not that well versed in `javascript` to get that specific vend code value and assign it to a go variable in the modal and use it to call function `"VendorByVendCode()"` in the template.

I have also included the `go.mod` and `go.sum` for reference.

Currently, I always get the last value for vend code from the loop. I want to get the vend code that is clicked. Here are my files, `main.go` and `index.html`:

```
main.go:
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

// Vendacct : information about a vendacct in the database
type Vendacct struct {
    Id            int    `json:"id"`
    VendCode      string `json:"vendcode"`
    MasterAcctNum string `json:"masteracctnum"`
    RepName       string `json:"repname"`
    RepPhone      string `json:"repphone"`
}

// Vendor : information about a vendor
type Vendor struct {
    Id       int    `json:"id"`
    VendCode string `json:"vendcode" validate:"required"`
    Name     string `json:"name" validate:"required"`
    Website  string `json:"website"  validate:""`
    Phone    string `json:"phone"  validate:""`
    Email    string `json:"email"  validate:""`
}

// VendacctSlice : slice of vendacct struct []Vendacct
var VendacctSlice []Vendacct

// VendSlice : slice of Vendor struct []Vendor
var VendSlice []Vendor

// var tmpl template.Template

// MD :
var MD Data

func Init() {
    // populate VendacctSlice
    a1 := Vendacct{1, "1001", "X23Z4", "Jackson Brown", "2143334444"}
    a2 := Vendacct{2, "1002", "JJF23", "Mike Malone", "8882225555"}
    a3 := Vendacct{3, "1003", "KR824", "Trey Book", "666333444"}
    a4 := Vendacct{4, "1004", "P23X1", "Cat Run", "9997771111"}
    VendacctSlice = append(VendacctSlice, a1)
    VendacctSlice = append(VendacctSlice, a2)
    VendacctSlice = append(VendacctSlice, a3)
    VendacctSlice = append(VendacctSlice, a4)
    
    // populate VendSlice
    b1 := Vendor{1, "1001", "Sun LLC", "www.mysun.com", "5559990000", "a@a.com"}
    b2 := Vendor{2, "1002", "Image Inc.", "www.image.com", "2221113333", "b@b.com"}
    b3 := Vendor{3, "1003", "Walkers LLC", "www.walkers.com", "4448763434", "c@c.com"}
    b4 := Vendor{4, "1004", "Hill Top Inc", "www.hill.com", "4764536678", "d@d.com"}
    VendSlice = append(VendSlice, b1)
    VendSlice = append(VendSlice, b2)
    VendSlice = append(VendSlice, b3)
    VendSlice = append(VendSlice, b4)
    
    MD.Vendaccts = VendacctSlice
    MD.Vendors = VendSlice
    
    // initialize the routes.
    Route()
}

// Route :
func Route() {
    var Router = mux.NewRouter()
    
    Router.HandleFunc("/", IndexHandler)
    http.Handle("/", Router)
    
    Router.HandleFunc("/index", IndexHandler)
    http.Handle("/index", Router)
}

// Data : Contains info needed for managing a Vendacct.
type Data struct {
    Vendacct  Vendacct
    Vendaccts []Vendacct
    Vendor    Vendor
    Vendors   []Vendor
}

// IndexHandler :
func IndexHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    
    tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles("index.html")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    
    uidata := &Data{
        Vendaccts: MD.Vendaccts,
        Vendacct:  MD.Vendacct,
        Vendor:    MD.Vendor,
        Vendors:   MD.Vendors,
    }
    err = tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "index.html", uidata)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return
} // end of function: IndexHandler()

// VendorByVendCode : returns the value of a specific Vendor record from slice []Vendor
// based on its VendCode value
func (Vendacct) VendorByVendCode(vendcode string, vs []Vendor) (vend Vendor) {
    for _, v := range vs {
        if v.VendCode == vendcode {
            vend = v
        }
    }
    return vend
} // end of function: VendorByVendCode()

func main() {
    Init()
    
    fmt.Println("Server is started at: http://localhost:8001")
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":8001", nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

--------------------------------------------------

index.html:
{{define "index.html"}}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <title>Go Modal Example</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row no-gutters d-flex font-weight-bold bg-info text-white py-2 my-2">
            <div class="col col-sm-3">
                Vendor Code
            </div>
            <div class="col col-sm-3">
                Master Acct Num
            </div>
            <div class="col col-sm-3">
                Acct Rep Name
            </div>
            <div class="col col-sm-3">
                Acct Rep Phone
            </div>
        </div>

        {{$VC := 0}}
        {{$Vend := 0}}
        {{$Vends := .Vendors}}
        {{$VA := .Vendacct}}

        <!-- details row -->
        {{range $record := .Vendaccts}}
        <div class="row no-gutters d-flex">
            {{$VC = .VendCode}}
    

            <!-- display a vendor associated with this Vendacct -->
            <div class="col col-sm-3 bg-light">
                <div><a href="#VendorModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#vendorModal" data-id="{{$VC}}"
                        title="Vendor Info">{{$VC}}</a>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col col-sm-3 bg-light">
                {{.MasterAcctNum}}
            </div>
            <div class="col col-sm-3 bg-light">
                {{.RepName}}
            </div>
            <div class="col col-sm-3 bg-light">
                {{.RepPhone}}
            </div>

        </div>
        <hr />
        {{ end }}

        <!-- START: Modal named vendAccountsModal to show Vendor Accounts list for any location this vendor is providing service -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="vendorModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    
                    {{$Vend = $VA.VendorByVendCode $VC $Vends}}
                    <!-- Modal Header -->
                    <div class="modal-header bg-info text-white py-2 my-0">
                        <div class="row no-gutters">
                            <h4>Vendor Info for: {{$Vend.VendCode}} - {{$Vend.Name}}</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Modal body -->
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="id" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Vendor Id:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <input type="text" readonly class="form-control" id="id" value="{{$Vend.Id}}">
                            </div>
                            <label for="vendcode" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Vendor Code:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <input type="text" readonly class="form-control" name="vendcode" id="vendcode"
                                    value="{{$Vend.VendCode}}">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Vendor Name:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <input type="text" readonly class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Vendor Name"
                                    value="{{$Vend.Name}}">
                            </div>
                            <label for="website" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Website:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <input type="text" readonly class="form-control" id="website" name="website"
                                    placeholder="Vendor Website" value="{{$Vend.Website}}">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="phone" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Main Phone:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <input type="text" readonly class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Vendor Main Phone"
                                    value="{{$Vend.Phone}}">
                            </div>

                            <label for="email" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email:</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <input type="text" readonly class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email"
                                    value="{{$Vend.Email}}">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <hr />
                    </div>

                    <!-- Modal footer -->
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END: Modal named vendAccountsModal to show Vendor Accounts list -->
    </div>
</body>

</html>
{{end}}
```